# How to mock/test Mainframe file I/O (JZOS) for a java program in windows?

Tags: java, mainframe, zos

While developing Java programs to read/process & write mainframe files , how can this file i/o functionality (using JZOS utility) be tested in the developers local environment (windows PC) ?

> Is there a way to safely mock/test the file i/o feature in developers
>   local environment rather than, every time moving the code to mainframe
>   and test the file i/o feature ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JZOS has a [file factory](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSYKE2_7.1.0/com.ibm.java.zsecurity.api.71.doc/com.ibm.jzos/com/ibm/jzos/FileFactory.html) which can be used on non z/OS platforms as long as the file name is not an MVS data set.

Comment: Looks like we will be reading and writing MVS datasets only using the JZOS utility (ZFile class), so have to find a way to mock it when developing code in windows platform

Comment: Why don't you create your own factory or even better use a dependency injection library like Guice with Mockito?

Comment: sure, will explore these options. Thank you.